# I need to edit and update XML file from a database VB NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a database that contains a lot of XML files as strings, and I want to update those files but only in certain conditions, for example I have this file :

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sads sap" x:Class="EmptyTask"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 ...
                  <t1:ReadProductParameterValue DisplayName="Normes tares" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Parameter="Normes tares" Value="[NormeTare]">
                    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                      </scg:Dictionary>
                    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                  </t1:ReadProductParameterValue>
                  ...
                      <t1:ReadProductParameterValue DisplayName="Normes volumes" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Parameter="Normes volumes" Value="[NormeVol]">
                        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                          </scg:Dictionary>
                        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                      </t1:ReadProductParameterValue>
                      ...
     sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Increment="1" Variable="OccurencePesee">

                                                                          <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                                            <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                                                              <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                                                                            </scg:Dictionary>
                                                                          </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                                        </t1:IncrementSharedVariableValue>
...
...
...                                                                                                                      <t1:WriteSharedVariableValue BatchVariableName="{x:Null}" DisplayName="rec_tare_ou_vol_hors_norme" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Value="[local_tare_ou_vol_hors_norme]" Variable="rec_tare_ou_vol_hors_norme">
                                                                                                                        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                                                                                          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                                                                                                            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                                                                                                                          </scg:Dictionary>
                                                                                                                        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                                                                                      </t1:WriteSharedVariableValue>
                                                                                                                      <FlowStep.Next>
...
...
...                                                                                                                          <t1:ExecuteTask BackColor="{x:Null}" DateToExecute="{x:Null}" LowLevel="{x:Null}" UpLevel="{x:Null}" BypassVariable="{x:Null}" AutoStart="True" DisplayName="A118. Stand by BP (v.1)" Grouping="" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="250,55" Label="Stand by BP (v.1)" Tache="8529de33-9721-4449-83d4-79b7fd5590f0" LockingTask="True" TypePoste="Remplissage">
                                                                                                                            <t1:ExecuteTask.Arguments>
                                                                                                                              ...
  </Flowchart>
</Activity>
```

Here I want to modify in this exact node

```
<t1:ExecuteTask BackColor="{x:Null}" DateToExecute="{x:Null}" LowLevel="{x:Null}" UpLevel="{x:Null}" BypassVariable="{x:Null}" AutoStart="True" DisplayName="A118. Stand by BP (v.1)" Grouping="" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="250,55" Label="Stand by BP (v.1)" Tache="8529de33-9721-4449-83d4-79b7fd5590f0" LockingTask="True" TypePoste="Remplissage">
                                                                                                                                <t1:ExecuteTask.Arguments>
```

"ExecuteTask" and replace it by "ExTasks" and "Tache" by "TaskID" and resave it to my DB 
How can I do it using VB.NET .. ?
I did it by using some sql commands but sometimes, it substitutes names that I do not want to modify so I really have to be specific, and specify the node where I want to edit and update..

Answer (score 0):

Very simple using xml linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim executeTask As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "ExecuteTask").FirstOrDefault()
        executeTask.SetAttributeValue("BackColor", "purple")
    End Sub

End Module
```